# Regex expression that excludes underscores, but only if they are right before a number or an uppercase letter?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

i have a string that represents a filename that comes with an incorporated  business unit code + a timestamp, like this: **alfin_cf_cashflowcomposition_X0826_20180726122003.csv**

I want to get exclude the BU code and the timestamp and end up  with the stripped name, so i want to get this: **alfin_cf_cashflowcomposition.csv**

So far i've managed to match only the lowercase letters, the dots and the underscores (thus excluding the uppercase X and the numbers that represent the timestamp).

I used this simple expression: **/[a-z._]** and got this result: **alfin_cf_cashflowcomposition__.csv**

Notice that there are 2 underscores just before ".csv". I do not want those there.

I only want the underscores if the next character is a lowercase letter.

I need to write a regex that ignores underscores if the next character is either an uppercase letter or a number.

Any idea on how i can achieve that?

Comment: Try `[a-z.]|(?<=[a-z])_(?=[a-z])` or `[a-z.]*[a-z](?:[_][a-z](?:[a-z.]*[a-z])?)*`. Please share your code.

Comment: Try `[A-Z0-9_](?![a-z])` [here](https://regex101.com/r/slYWfj/1), replacing with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex for this. You can strip the extension, split the rest of the filename and take all parts except the last two.

I implemented this simple code in javascript.

```js
const orig_filename = "alfin_cf_cashflowcomposition_X0826_20180726122003.csv";

function strip_codes (orig){
  const extpos = orig.lastIndexOf('.');
  const nameparts = orig.substr(0,extpos).split('_');
  const ext = orig.substr(extpos);
  const name = nameparts
    .slice(0, nameparts.length - 2)
    .join('_');
  return name + ext;
}

console.log(strip_codes(orig_filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use`_.[A-Z,0-9].*(?=.csv)` this regex it works.
you can test it online herehttps://regexr.com/